# Integrate a Python Project with a Visual Studio C++ Console Application?

Tags: c++, python

I now have **a Python project** that is in charge of generating the simulation data and visualizing the simulation and processed data. **A C++ console application** is already available in my Visual Studio.

The **processing sequence** is as follows:

1. Python project generates the raw data into `data.txt`.
2. Visual Studio C++ console application takes in `data.txt` and processes the data, and finally outputs `results.txt`.
3. Python project takes in `results.txt` and visualizes it with `matplotlib`.

I am now doing it manually, and it works perfectly ok for one run. However, it becomes extremely troublesome when I want to have multiple runs.

**Questions:**

1. How may I integrate them together? Integrate Python project into Visual Studio or integrate C++ console application into Spyder (my Python IDE)?
2. Currently, I manually enter the debugging parameters in the C++ console application debugging property. How may I make it automatic? i.e. After Python project generates `data.txt`, the `data.txt` gets automatically taken in as parameters by the C++ console application?

Comment: This doesn't seem specific enough to be answerable.  We don't know what "troublesome" means, for one thing.  As it is an implementation issue, it probably is better suited for Stack Overflow, but you need to make it specific enough to be answerable.  Describe the problem, and include valid code to reproduce it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Thanks for the comment! By troublesome I mean I have to manually change the debug parameters for every next run. Could you please kindly help move it to SO? :) Thanks!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng - can you edit the question to make your problem clear then it can be migrated to Stack Overflow. As it stands now it probably won't get an answer and might even get closed quite quickly.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for the kind advice! But I really have no idea how can I "make it clean". I have two big projects and I don't how can I condense them into very clear codes.

Comment: @ChrisF: I find the question not very good, but clear enough to answer. Would you be please so kind and migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE stands for Indegrated **Development** Environment. It is not concerned with running your application except for debugging. There is no point integrating the IDEs, the user won't have them installed.

What you should do is make of of the applications *run* the other, directly, not involving either IDE.

You can execute external process from Python using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module [(python3 doc)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

You can execute external process from C++ using the [system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) function [(windows doc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4b6wz4t.aspx) (platform independent, not very powerful, but should be enough for your purpose) or using the windows-specific [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface (on POSIX, you use the [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) interface), but I don't think you need this direction just now.